# HTML5 Canvas Tag

Tags: html, canvas

I'm working with the Canvas Tag to draw stuff to the screen, I have like 3 different shapes on the screen, and I want to make them linkable, they could be at different coordinates depending on the users interaction, is this possible with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach an `onmousemove` handler to the element, and track the offset, if you need the mouse coordinates. Then you can just draw onto the canvas with those coords.